# Conversion/comparison of different numeric types inside streams

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I'm having a problem with Stream API... again. The functionality I'm trying to implement isn't the hardest thing, but I'm having difficulties filtering since there are incompatible types and I don't how to make the comparison right. The idea is to get information about departments which the given sections are linked to.

`department.getSectionId()` returns `Long` while `Section::getId` is an `Integer` (which I can't change)

```
private List<DepartmentInfo> retrieveLinkedDepartments(final Collection<Section> sections) {
        return this.departmentDao
                .findAll()
                .stream()
                .filter(department -> department.getSectionId() != null)
                .filter(department -> department.getSectionId().equals(sections.stream().map(Section::getId)))                                           
                .map(this.departmentInfoMapper::map)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Of course the result of the main predicate is always false. I know the code is awful and I'm not defining conditions right, but I hope you get the idea. Maybe there's a possibility to somehow merge these collections or compare in a smart way.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you share you models `DepartmentInfo` and `Section` to be accurate.

Comment: In this line `department.getSectionId().equals(sections.stream().map(Section::getId))` you are comparing an `id` to a `Stream`, that is why it is always false. It has nothing to do with `Long` vs. `Integer` in this specific case.

Comment: @Hulk yeah, I discovered that in a debugger. Just wanted to be as concise as possible writing the question. I just didn't know how to compare ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of now you are comparing a `Long` and a `Steam<Integer>` which will always return false.

You can flip around your logic a little and use a `mapToLong` to convert the int's to `Long`'s:

```
private List<DepartmentInfo> retrieveLinkedDepartments(final Collection<Section> sections) {
    return this.departmentDao
               .findAll()
               .stream()
               .filter(department -> department.getSectionId() != null)
               .filter(department -> sections.stream()
                                 .mapToLong(Section::getId)                                     
                                 .anyMatch(department.getSectionId()::equals))                                           
               .map(this.departmentInfoMapper::map)
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

This will convert `Section::getId` to a `Stream<Long>`, and then filter through the `Stream` to see if any of the `department.getSectionId` equals the Id.

Comment: That's indeed really nice. Thank you for your effort!

Answer (score 4):

You're possibly looking for something like :

```
private List<DepartmentInfo> retrieveLinkedDepartments(final Collection<Section> sections) {
    Set<Long> sectionIds = sections.stream()
            .map(Section::getId)
            .map(Long::valueOf)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet()); // collect all the possible sectionIds
    return this.departmentDao
            .findAll()
            .stream()
            .filter(department -> department.getSectionId() != null)'
            // validate if the sectionIds include this department's section id or not
            .filter(department -> sectionIds.contains(department.getSectionId()))
            .map(this.departmentInfoMapper::map)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

> Offcourse the result of the main predicate is always false

That's because you've been comparing `Long` generated using `department.getSectionId()` with `Stream<Integer>` generated using `sections.stream().map(Section::getId)`, the comparison of these two types would always be unequal and hence the resultant `false`.

***Edit***: As pointed by Holger in comments, the code for preparation of the `Set` can be improved as:

```
Set<Long> sectionIds = sections.stream()
            .mapToLong(Section::getId)
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: Instead of `.map(Section::getId) .map(Long::valueOf)` you could use `.mapToLong(Section::getId).boxed()` or even simpler, `.map(s -> (long)s.getId())`. But generally, using a prepared `Set` is preferable to streaming over the `sections` again and again…

Comment: @Holger Well yes, preparing the `Set` seems better to me as well. I meant the other approach was interesting because of the way it reused the code in the question smartly.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's a nice alternative!

Answer (score 2):

In this line `department.getSectionId().equals(sections.stream().map(Section::getId)` you're comparing a `Long` against a `Stream<Integer>` which will always yield false.

instead map the `Section` ids to a `Set<Long>` and then use `contains` in the `filter` operation:

```
Set<Long> ids = sections.stream() // Stream<Section>
                        .map(Section::getId) //Stream<Integer>
                        .filter(Objects::nonNull) // remove potential null elements
                        .map(Integer::longValue) // Stream<Long>
                        .collect(Collectors.toSet()); //Set<Long>

return this.departmentDao
           .findAll()
           .stream()
           .filter(department -> department.getSectionId() != null)
           .filter(department -> ids.contains(department.getSectionId()))
           .map(this.departmentInfoMapper::map)
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I think the line `.filter(department -> department.getSectionId() != null)` is not necessary, because `Set.contains` will return `false` if the set doesn't contain the `null` element.